# Monomorphism in the category of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let $(f, f^{\#}): X \rightarrow Y$ be a map of schemes. The stacks project gives a criterion for $f$ to be a monomorphism (see tag [01L6](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01L6) in the stacks project): if

(a): $f$ is a monomorphism in the category of topological spaces;

(b): $f^\#: f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$ is an epimorphism in the category of sheaves of rings on $X$.

then $(f, f^\#)$ is a monomorphism in the category of schemes.

My question is: is this an if and only if? And if not, what could be a counterexample?

P.S. The lemma in the stacks project is slightly less general, where $f^\#$ is required to be surjective as a map of sheaves of rings.  But looking at the argument it is immediate that the same thing holds with surjectiveness replaced by epimorphism.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56591/what-are-the-monomorphisms-in-the-category-of-schemes

Comment: looks like the nodal curve example from David Rydh's answer here will be a counterexample right? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like